# Java-Jsoup, scrape html

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am using Jsoup with Java to Parse an HTML file. My question is how can I just extract the line that says "Hourly Rate: 23,016 orders"
I am parsing a lot of files, so the number next to the Hourly Rate will change.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='background:#DEDEDF'>
<span style='font-size:18.0pt'><b>Testing</b></span></p>
Hourly Rate: 23,016 orders<br>
<table border=0 cellpadding=0>
<tr valign=top>
<td>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the MsoNormal class then use a regular expression to look for a number i.e.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
Element msoNormal = doc.getElementsByClass("MsoNormal").first();
if(msoNormal!=null){
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+,[0-9]+");
  Matcher m = pattern.matcher(msoNormal.text());
  if(matcher.find())
    System.out.println(m.get());
}
```

Comment: THanks for the response selig"
I am getting eorrosthe "Pattern" and "Matcher" classes.My IDE cannot find them.

Comment: You need to import them from `java.util.regex`

Answer (score 1):

I just added this code:

```
 String HourlyRate = doc.body().ownText();
//String text = doc.body().text();

System.out.println(HourlyRate);
```

This Printed out:
Hourly Rate: 23,016 orders